# Why does the exception handler look up the system call table?

Tags: linux, exception, linux-kernel, system-calls, interrupt

I am learning how system calls work.

I know that for a system call to take place, the exception handler is invoked via a software interrupt. The exception handler then reads the system call ID from the eax register and then looks-up the system call table for the function's absolute address.

How does it find the absolute address of the function from the system call table?

Comment: The system call table is an array of function addresses. The system call ID is the index into the array.

Comment: See [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table)

Comment: Your title asks "why", but the question asks "how". What are you really trying to find out?

Comment: @Barmar Can you just put it as an answer? I will mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system call table is a [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table), which is an array of function pointers. The system call number is simply the index into this array.